# How do I access the address that a member of a class is pointing to while within the class?

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml

*input.cpp Function That Has The Error*

```
void Input::isKeyPressed()
{

    if ( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed ( sf::Keyboard::S ) )
    {
        // Here's The Error
        *Input::playerOne.move(0.0 ,  1.0);

    }

}
```

*More Details*

This function is the implementation of the class *Input* and the class has a private variable for a pointer to the *sf::RectangleShape* in the *int main()* of the program.

I am trying to access that instantiation of *sf::RectangleShape* in order to move the object down on the screen. I don't want to create a global variables class just to make this work. I just want to be able to access that method for that specific object.

Comment: `(*Input::playerOne).move()`

Comment: `playerOne->move(0.0 ,  1.0);` (And you should consider picking up a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).)

Comment: @molbdnilo I would pick up a book but I already have a solid understanding of c++. It's just in terms of classes that I need to get better at. I am nearly 17 and live in the UK. In September, I will be starting my second year in college and will be doing a lot of OOP and so I will be improving my skills then. C++ was my first ever used programming language. I self taught myself and absolutely love the language. Even so, I can understand why people don't recommend C++ as a starting language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the *pointer to member* operator:

`Input::playerOne->move(0.0, 1.0);`

The explicit scope resolution `Input::` is not required, you can rewrite to

`playerOne->move(0.0, 1.0);`

Comment: It is in a different file to the class definition. The class definition is in input.h. I'm doing the implementation in input.cpp.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The *preprocessor* substitutes the contents of `input.h` for `#include.h`, and the *compiler* compiles the single file.

Comment: Then the code::blocks IDE autocompete/suggest is total bollocks